# Is there a R function to order by character or factor of intervals?

Tags: r, dplyr

After several functions I get a table, which has ordered characters, some starting with "(" or "[" followed by numbers. (intervals, coming from a cut(x) on the data)

What i want to achieve is an order by the startvalue of the invervals, so that (100,124] does not come before (70,100] (see example) 
edit: the order of column1 (class) should stay as it is.

well i tried to do it with the order and setorder from data.table but failed so far. I think I need to split the column with strsplit and then order by the first element of it, but that can't be the "best" solution

```
test <- data.frame(class = c("class1",   "class1",   "class1",   "class1",   "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2"),
                   attr = c("1","2","4","5","(100,124]", "(124,180]" ,"(180,Inf]", "(37,50]" ,  "(5,37]"  ,  "(50,56]"  , "(56,70]"  ,"(70,100]"  ,"[0,5]" ),
                  value = c(415.14,115.13,422.52,37.07,167.40,135.04,67.01,280.03,81.18,237.83,285.62,302.63,3.37))
```

aim:

```
class   attr    value
class1  1   415.14
class1  2   115.13
class1  4   422.52
class1  5   37.07
class2  [0,5]   3.37
class2  (5,37]  81.18
class2  (37,50] 280.03
class2  (50,56] 237.83
class2  (56,70] 285.62
class2  (70,100]    302.63
class2  (100,124]   167.40
class2  (124,180]   135.04
class2  (180,Inf]   67.01
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) base R** Replace comma and everything after it as well as any non-digits with an empty string.  Convert that to numeric and compute the indexes that would order it, `o`.  Finally subscript `test` by `o`.

```
o <- with(test, order(class, as.numeric(gsub(",.*|\\D", "", attr))))
test[o, ]
```

giving:

```
    class      attr     value
1  class1         1  977.0947
2  class1         2  299.9418
3  class1         4 1398.7519
4  class1         5  170.8434
13 class2     [0,5]  299.1390
9  class2    (5,37]  326.5092
8  class2   (37,50]  923.6778
10 class2   (50,56]  734.9950
11 class2   (56,70]  820.7536
12 class2  (70,100]  779.0926
5  class2 (100,124]  308.5136
6  class2 (124,180]  234.6386
7  class2 (180,Inf]  100.1264
```

**1a)** This variation would also work. It matches an optional initial non-digit followed by digits followed by anything else and replaces it all with just the digits.  Then it proceeds as above.

```
o <- with(test, order(class, as.numeric(gsub("^\\D?(\\d+).*", "\\1", attr))))
test[o, ]
```

**2) dplyr**

The above could also be done using dplyr `arrange` like this:

```
library(dplyr) 

test %>% arrange(class, attr %>% gsub(",.*|\\D", "", .) %>% as.numeric)
```

**2a)** A variation is to remove (/[ and the comma etc. parts in separate sub statements:

```
test %>% 
  arrange(class, attr %>% 
                   sub("^\\D", "", .) %>%
                   sub(",.*", "", .) %>%
                    as.numeric)
```

Comment: that would be perfeclty  working if the order of the first column would not matter, but it should stay like it is (already ordered)

Comment: OK. Have made that change.  It now orders by `class` and then by leading digits in `attr` within `class`.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
   arrange(class, as.numeric(str_extract(attr, "\\d+")))
#  class      attr  value
#1  class1         1 415.14
#2  class1         2 115.13
#3  class1         4 422.52
#4  class1         5  37.07
#5  class2     [0,5]   3.37
#6  class2    (5,37]  81.18
#7  class2   (37,50] 280.03
#8  class2   (50,56] 237.83
#9  class2   (56,70] 285.62
#10 class2  (70,100] 302.63
#11 class2 (100,124] 167.40
#12 class2 (124,180] 135.04
#13 class2 (180,Inf]  67.01
```

NOTE: There was no set seed

Answer (score 0):

`stringi` alternative using the same logic as @G. Grothendieck's solution. It extracts the first sequence of digits in the `attr` column:

```
o2 <- order(test$class, as.numeric(stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(test$attr, "\\d+")))
test[o2, ]

    class      attr     value
1  class1         1  977.0947
2  class1         2  299.9418
3  class1         4 1398.7519
4  class1         5  170.8434
13 class2     [0,5]  299.1390
9  class2    (5,37]  326.5092
8  class2   (37,50]  923.6778
10 class2   (50,56]  734.9950
11 class2   (56,70]  820.7536
12 class2  (70,100]  779.0926
5  class2 (100,124]  308.5136
6  class2 (124,180]  234.6386
7  class2 (180,Inf]  100.1264
```